# How to update STRIPE CHECKOUT SESSION attributes RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, attributes, stripe-payments, checkout

In rails 5, I create a stripe session in the show action of the order controller. I have also an update action which handles if the user chooses a delivery or a pick and collect for that order. In the update method, I try to update the stripe session by adding a shipping_address_collection attribute, so that the stripe checkout page displays a delivery address area. I manage to modify correctly the stripe session object, but not to save it. I have a :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `save' for #<Stripe::Checkout::Session:0x00007fb60fe5f138>
```

Order controller:

```
def show
 @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
      payment_method_types: ['card'],

      customer: customer.id,

      line_items: line_items_order,

      success_url: order_messages_url(@order),
      cancel_url:  order_failure_message_url(@order)
      )

       @user.stripe_id = customer.id
       @user.save


   @order.checkout_session_id = @session.id
   @order.save
end

def update
 @order = Order.find(params[:id])
 @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.retrieve("#{@order.checkout_session_id}")
 
    if @order.collect_address == nil && @order.shipping_zone != nil

    allowed_countries_item = {:allowed_countries => ['GB', 'BE', 'CZ', 'FR', 'DK', 'DE', 'EE', 'IE', 'HR', 'IT', 'CY', 'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'HU', 'MT', 'NL', 'AT', 'PL', 'RO', 'SI', 'SK', 'FI', 'SE', 'IS', 'LI', 'NO', 'CH', 'PT', 'ES', 'ME', 'MK', 'AL', 'RS', 'TR', 'DZ', 'MA', 'IL']}
    @session[:shipping_address_collection] = allowed_countries_item
    @session.shipping_address_collection.save
    end

    @order.save
    redirect_to order_path(@order)
  end
```

Is there a way to do it or should I create 2 different sessions depending on the attributes I want ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stripe Checkout Sessions cannot be updated.  [The API only allows you to create, retrieve, and list them.](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions#checkout_sessions)  You'll need to create a new Session instead of trying to update an existing one.

Comment: Thanks @justin, I searched all possible resources and was surprised I couldn't find another way but to create a new session. Seems weird to me. Now I am fixed

Comment: Glad to hear you got this sorted out!  Remember to mark this answer as the one that worked for you so other people who see this question can see what worked. 